# Django paginate_by doesn't work correctly

Tags: python, django, django-views

My pagination doesn't work in this case, can you help?

My search in controller:

```py
class PostSearchView(ListView):
    paginate_by = 5
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']

    def get_context_data(self):
        inp_value = self.request.GET.get('search', '')
        context = super().get_context_data()
        objects = Post.objects.filter(title__icontains=inp_value).order_by('-date_posted')
        context['posts'] = objects
        context['inp_value'] = inp_value
        return context
```

My form rendered from my view:

```html
<form class="form-inline" method='GET' action="{% url 'blog-search' %}">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type='text' name='search' value="{{ inp_value }}">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" id="search_submit" type="Search" >Search</button>
</form>
```

I tried doing it with the `get_queryset` method, but when I push the second page button, the request results None, and the results contain all posts which do not match the search query. I use `get_context_data` to return input search value again in form, but pagination in this case doesn't work correctly.

```py
    def get_queryset(self):
        search_query = self.request.GET.get('search', '')
        return Post.objects.filter(title__icontains=search_query).order_by('-date_posted')
```

Comment: Try to use the `get_queryset` approach, but in your template, use `page_obj` to display the items